# need the most efficient way to handle unique constraint errors

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am looking for the most efficient way to solve this situation:

We are an Oracle shop.  I need to load data from one table to another.  My source table, which contains 30 million rows, has a person identifier that is *supposed* to be unique, but it is not enforced so there are cases where it is not - about .1% of the time.  There is logic I can use to resolve the non-unique cases.  I want my target table to "enforce" the uniqueness of the identifier - so I have defined this identifier as my primary key.

(Note that the data that is loaded isn't a straight source table -> target table; there are a few look-up tables that are used too)

My goal: load this table as quickly as possible.  It's a lot of rows, so efficiency is key.

I have thought of a number of ways to address this, but I'm not sure what would be the most efficient.  My ideas include:

- Use MERGE (concerned about performance compared to an INSERT with an APPEND hint.)
- Change the SELECT statement of the load to include the logic to address the the non-unique cases
- Use error trapping to write the non-unique information to a separate table (where I would use the logic)
- Drop the primary key, load the data, fix the issues, add the key back

I am sure there are other methods that I haven't listed.

So - what's the fastest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can use `log errors into` together with the `insert` statement. Don't know if that is compatible with the `APPEND` hint though: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55097

Comment: if a duplicate row is a different person - then a merge will only allow you to update - not what you are looking for. if duplicates are new data then a merge is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am exploring the `log errors into` option, but thus far it seems really slow.  Duplicates are the same person.